Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl', although it's installed
I am struggling with this issue.
I have a small python project that is running inside a virtual environment. I installed this module as pip install openpyxl (I also tried pip3 install openpyxl or python3 -m pip install openpyxl with the same result).
When I run my script, I get this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

In the traceback, I see references to my version of python (3.11.8):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/scrapy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
             ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 160, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 357, in __init__
    super().__init__(settings)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 227, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = self._get_spider_loader(settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 221, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 79, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 34, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 63, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 106, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/adam/pythondev/myproj/app.py", line 17, in <module>
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

When I do pip list for my venv, I get
Package    Version
---------- -------
et-xmlfile 1.1.0
openpyxl   3.1.2
pip        24.0
setuptools 69.5.1
wheel      0.43.0

When I do pip list outside of my venv, there's no openpyxl.
When I do which python3, I get
/Users/adam/pythondev/myproj/.venv/bin/python

Based on googling, I apparently installed openpyxl to a wrong version of python? However, how do I fix this and install to my version of python? (python3 --version => Python 3.11.8)

You you running the script with your venv activated?

did you check which pip? Maybe use full path to install module /Users/adam/pythondev/myproj/.venv/bin/python -m pip install ... and the same full path when you check installed modules /Users/adam/pythondev/myproj/.venv/bin/python -m pip list

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

in code you can run print( sys.executable ) to see full path to python which runs code. Maybe it uses different Python.

@h0r53 Yes, I do

@furas added the full Traceback

If you say that the python in your venv is that python3, then activate your venv, then install with python3 -m pip install openpyxl. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2812520/2745495

If you execute pip show openpyxl in terminal you should see the location of where the package was installed. You should see the name of your environment somewhere in the location path.
If you have altered your $PATH system environment variable in the past then this could also be an issue.
You seem to be using venv for your virtual environment. After running python3 -m venv <PATH_TO_ENVIRONMENT>/<ENVIRONMENT_NAME> be sure to activate the environment using source <PATH_TO_ENVIRONMENT/<ENVIRONMENT_NAME>/bin/activate then pip install openpyxl.
